# How can I find out, before upgrading, whether a reboot will be required

Tags: apt

I'd like to know before-hand if a reboot will be required. I've tried to get verbose output during a simulated upgrade to grep for `/run/reboot-required`. But that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you simulate an upgrade, the simulation doesn’t run any of the operations which lead to deciding whether a reboot is required or not; so it isn’t possible to determine automatically whether an upgrade would result in requesting a reboot.

If you’re really interested, you could look at the maintainer scripts of all the packages which are about to be upgraded, figure out what conditions lead to a reboot request, and determine whether those conditions will be met during the upgrade. But that’s a rather unrealistic endeavour.

Comment: I was hoping there was a convention of including the actual file in the package if the maintainers knew a reboot would be required... assuming you could determine the file was going to be included in the update actions.... but wishful thinking, I guess.

Comment: Interesting idea, but it wouldn’t work. For one thing, installing any two such packages would result in a conflict; for another, having a package which directly installs a file which is then removed would result in some tools considering the package to be broken.